# Minimize main-thread work on Nextjs (only Mobile view)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, next.js, next.js13

When I try to test my Nextjs project on PageSpeed Insights, I got two difference result, on Desktop view it ok, but on Mobile view I got the message  **Minimize main-thread work**. How can I solve this problem?

On Mobile view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGAyF.png)

On Desktop view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skt5u.png)

Improve perfomance on Nextjs Project

Comment: when you open the menu it tells you which part is actually causing the issue then you can work on them. take a look at this link: https://touch.marfeel.com/resources/blog/how-do-i-minimize-main-thread-work

Comment: On a nextjs (or any react) project your best bet is to cut as much JS as possible from the initial payload. This usually means having more lazy loaded components (that's using next's `dynamic`). Lazy load everything that's initially hidden like popups, drawers, slideshows, ...